# webscraping data from multiple urls

Tags: excel, vba, url

I am building an excel file for my stocks, I want to get a lot of data from many urls. I solved this with powerquery, but it is very slow, so I want to use a vba script instead.

I can get it work for a single url, but not for many.

Sub ScrapDataUsingXMLHTTP()

```
Dim XMLRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim URLs As String
Dim i As Integer

    XMLRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.boerse.de/aktien/Microsoft-Aktie/US5949181045", False
    XMLRequest.send

     If XMLRequest.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox XMLRequest.Status & " - " & XMLRequest.statusText
            Exit Sub
    End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLRequest.responseText

Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("content_container")
Set HTMLTable = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

'Debug.Print HTMLTable.className

WriteTableToWorksheet HTMLTable
```

End Sub

this works, but when I want to refer to my table contents (URLs, stored in my table), it's not working. How to fix?

Sub ScrapDataUsingXMLHTTP()

```
Dim XMLRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim URLs As String
Dim i As Integer



    XMLRequest.Open "GET", ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabelle1").DataBodyRange(1, 2).Select, False
    XMLRequest.send

     If XMLRequest.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox XMLRequest.Status & " - " & XMLRequest.statusText
            Exit Sub
    End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLRequest.responseText

Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("content_container")
Set HTMLTable = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

'Debug.Print HTMLTable.className

WriteTableToWorksheet HTMLTable
```

Comment: It would help if you could describe what it is that is not working as you expect. What were you expecting, and what happened instead? If there are any error messages, copy and paste them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, finally found my mistake. I had to remove the ".select" from my table reference. I can loop through urls now from my table with some i/j vars. Thank you anyways..